# Angular 2 surrounding an input tag with div via directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create a directive which takes an input element and surrounds it with a div, so for example, my html would be something like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" inputWrapper />
```

and the desired outcome:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="from-control" />
</div>
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[inputWrapper]'
})
export class InputWrapperDirective {
    constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        // what goes here?
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe angular2 directives are more frequently used for adding behaviour to existing DOM elements and not generally used for altering the DOM.

Comment: I am curious why you would not just add the <div> tags around the element in your html.

Comment: I'm trying to make it as reusable as possible, Essentially I want to append html after the input tag, but need it inside the parent div to do some inline styling

Comment: Instead of a directive, I would probably use a Component.

Answer (score 23):

here is how you do it with a directive. The code uses Renderer2, which I think is Angular 4. Probably the same thing can be achieved with Renderer (which is marked deprecated now)

I did all the work in the `ngAfterViewInit` method. You may probably use the constructor instead.

```js
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
    selector: '[inputWrapper]'
})
export class InputWrapperDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private _renderer:Renderer2, private _el: ElementRef) {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // Get parent of the original input element
        var parent = this._el.nativeElement.parentNode;

        // Create a div
        var divElement = this._renderer.createElement("div");

        // Add class "input-wrapper"
        this._renderer.addClass(divElement, "input-wrapper");

        // Add the div, just before the input
        this._renderer.insertBefore(parent, divElement, this._el.nativeElement);

        // Remove the input
        this._renderer.removeChild(parent, this._el.nativeElement);

        // Remove the directive attribute (not really necessary, but just to be clean)
        this._renderer.removeAttribute(this._el.nativeElement, "inputWrapper"); 

        // Re-add it inside the div
        this._renderer.appendChild(divElement, this._el.nativeElement);

    }

}
```

Comment: As a side note, I am not saying that going for a Directive approach is better or worse than using a Component. I am simply answering your original questions, which was how to do it with a directive.

Comment: Will the ngmodel binding work in case we remove and add new elements like above?

Comment: Actually, appendChild moves a node. So, previous removeChild can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version, this one works with Renderer, instead of Renderer2. Notice that here I am doing the work in the constructor, deferring it to `AfterViewInit` does not work.

```js
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[inputWrapper]'
})
export class InputWrapperDirective {
    constructor(private _renderer:Renderer, private _el: ElementRef) {
        // Remove the inputWrapper attribute (not really necessary, but just to be clean)
        this._renderer.setElementAttribute(this._el.nativeElement, "inputWrapper", null);

        // Get parent of the original input element
        var parent = this._el.nativeElement.parentNode;

        // Create a div and add it to the parent
        // Note: it seems that Renderer creates the element in the right place,
        // no need to specify where.
        var divElement = this._renderer.createElement(parent, "div");

        // Add class "input-wrapper"
        this._renderer.setElementClass(divElement, "input-wrapper", true);

        // Move the input as a child of the div
        divElement.appendChild(this._el.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a component...

Here is what I would do:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'input-wrapper',
    template: '<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class InputWrapperComponent {}
```

In the template, the `<ng-content>` tag means that whatever your `<input-wrapper>` tag is wrapped around goes here.

Note that this component template is `<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>`. You can change the "div" to be whatever you want it to be...

Wherever you wanted to use this you would not just annotate a tag, you would need to do something like this:

```
<input-wrapper>
    <!-- Anything you want wrapped goes here -->
</input-wrapper>
```

That is fairly reusable... Change your template and you would change all wrappings.